# bwrap execvp no such file or directory when ro-bind'ing non-root path

Tags: linux, sandbox, bwrap

When I bind filesystem root it works

```
~> bwrap --ro-bind / / -- which which
/usr/bin/which
```

however when I bind non-root it fails

```
~> bwrap --ro-bind /usr /usr -- which which
bwrap: execvp which: No such file or directory
```

even though `/usr/bin/which` is in `/usr`.

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not bind the *interpreter* for that binary – `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or similar. (The kernel itself doesn't actually understand dynamically linked binaries, instead they specify a loader in their ELF header. It works very similar to the #! line for scripts.)

Even on systems with a merged /usr, this file is commonly still in /lib. (And on systems *without* a merged /usr, lots of other required libraries such as libc.so are in /lib as well.)

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.
`bwrap --ro-bind /usr /usr --ro-bind /lib64 /lib64 -- which which` works

Comment: The example given by @Rawieo does not work for me. Still getting the same error.